# How can I add the Accept-Ranges header to the response in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm getting a file from another server and pass it to the client with the following code
(**to download the file I'm using axios**):

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    downloadFile(res)
})

async function downloadFile(res) {
    const url = 'http://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4'

    console.log('Connecting …')
    const { data, headers } = await Axios({
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
    })


    const totalLength = headers['content-length']
    let offset = 0

    res.set({
        "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4"',
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Content-Length": totalLength,
        // "Range": `bytes=${offset}` // my problem is here ....
    });

    data.on('data', (chunk) => {
        res.write(chunk)
    })

    data.on('close', function () {
        res.end('success')
    })

    data.on('error', function () {
        res.send('something went wrong ....')
    })

}
```

So far everything is working properly.

my problem is to add the Accept-Ranges header, I tried a lot but I do not know How to do it?
any help will be appreciated ...

Comment: do you get any error? or it just doesn't appear in the response?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing you need to do is to add it here:

```js
res.set({
        "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4"',
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Content-Length": totalLength,
        "Accept-Ranges": // add here the value your server accepts
    });
```

Check the `Accept-Ranges` documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Ranges

Its syntax is like this:

```
Accept-Ranges: <range-unit>
Accept-Ranges: none
```

Comment: @germanio- Thanks for your answer,
Can you complete your snippet, according to my code, I do not know exactly what I should assign to "Accept-Ranges"

Comment: It is used to support partial requests, that could allow a user to resume a download where it was left. The value will depend on what your server supports. `none` if it is not supported, a range in bytes otherwise.

Comment: I guess you can start by setting `none` to begin with, as long you are not downloading huge files, you should be fine to continue development. Then you can come back to this and make it more complex.

Comment: Also, check this out, here is the sintax for the byte ranges: https://apimirror.com/http/rfc7233#section-2.1